# Transfer wordpress from server to a server

Tags: database, wordpress, hosting, transfer, domain-name

I do have two questions:

I have a paid web-hosting and a domain-name. (www.caselawofeu.com)

How is it possible to transfer from present server to a server of a new provider. And how does the transfer of domain-name work?

Can I pay the server in a new provider and to move the site now? And after that, domai-name will be allocated to the new server provider? Still I have payed my hosting.

Is there documentation, how to do that?

I newer done this before. Thanks for all of your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back up your directory and when you move it over to the other server keep the file structure the same from root up. This way you don't have to go through the SQL files to update file locations / preplan it. You redirect the domain to the new nameservers and within 1 hour - 24 hours that domain should be redirected at the new host.

Back up your SQL database with something like phpmyadmin and just do a database dump and make a new database on the new server and upload your database there. Goto your wp-config file and make sure your database connection information matches with your new host.

Make sure you do most of this before you switch the domain name if you don't know your servers ip if it uses cpanel, or others etc..

You can also move over all the files and the database and connect everything before the server and new domain connects. So when it does swap there won't be any downtime.

After that you should be good to go. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. When owner of my domain-name is server provider, he just sends me invoices for services, will he redirect the domain-name to the new server provider till 24 hours?

Comment: @PodujatieEu Sorry for the delay, but if you don't have access to the domain settings, as it was purchased through the same service as the hosting that you would need to go through the company to get the nameservers changed. Another thing you could do is get your domain switched to another provider and keep them separate so you have control over it.

Comment: @savunit Would transferring the database to another server make the images uploaded unto it transferred as well? Or would the images get  stored in the wordpress folder?

Comment: @marchemike Sorry for the very late response, images are stored in the upload folder within the Wordpress file structure. This would have to be moved also.

Answer (score 0):

For transfer your domain name to another hosting provider, you need AUTHORISATION CODE and your previous provider need to allow your domain for transfer. 

This can take maximum 5 (working) days.
During this days, you can use your new hosting, but DNS server is set "2" and when your new provider will have domainame, he change DNS to "1" and all is working :)

WORDPRESS!!!

I tryied to move from odl server to new one. No luck. But I had moved my (backup) MySQL and than installed new wordpress. In the middle of installation wordpress asked me to use old database, I click YES.
Now you have to move your templates, plugins and so on...

THIS WORKED FOR ME